# How do you convert a Hex value coming in a video container into a UTC timestamp?

Tags: c, datetime, video-processing, mp4parser

My mp4 container contains a value of (0XC64322C1) for creation time, and the analyzer interprets as 2009/05/27 17:02:57; How is this conversion done.A C code implementation for the same would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

That is the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1st, 1904. Googling this date reveals that lot of software uses this as an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing), and it appears to be a holdover from legacy days.

I found [this QuickTime file format specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html) which specifically refers to this date, as well as [this thread](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/What-s-with-12AM-Friday-January-01-1904/td-p/409440) and [this interesting (albeit a bit lengthy) blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html).